# What is my URL localHost when testing Android project on real device on a Mac?

Tags: android, macos, localhost, jax-ws, ksoap

I'm developing an Android Project using Android Studio and I'm using Netbeans jax_ws as my backend on my Mac 10.10.5. When I build my project and test it on a virtual device I use the soap URL this way:

```
final String URL = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/OurWS/OurWS?WSDL";
```

It works just fine. Now I want to test my project on a real device, so I created a signed APK so I can install the project on my Galaxy S6. My question then is what should I put in my URL localHost?

- i  implement Web Service as Statlees Session Bean  when created my webservice on netbeans !

Comment: `My mac 10.10.5 .. ` ??? What dit you say there?

Comment: mac os x yosemite version 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

The client should use the ip of the pc/mac where the server runs on.

Both should be in the same (W)LAN.